# Nina Simone "Love me or Leave me" and Bach

Tags: j-s-bach

When listening to Nina Simone's version of "Love me or Leave me" ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFKo9RGzg4s&ab_channel=NinaSimone-Topic) version), I have a feeling that she incorporates some classical music into her solo (around 1 minute to 2:20) - googling I found some references claiming she put Bach parts in it. E.g., [this source](https://thekidshouldseethis.com/post/nina-simone-love-me-or-leave-me) claims she puts Bach’s Fugue in C Major (on the version given there). I was wondering if there are actually parts of Bach music or its just "in the style of Bach". If there is a part of Bach, can someone refer me to the exact piece and to what part of the piece? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

She's certainly channelling Bach (until the final cadence when she slips in a bit of Beethoven!)   I'm hearing generic passage work in Bach's style rather than any specific quotes.  It's not fully worked-out counterpoint, but there's plenty of interesting melodic conntent in the left hand.

I wonder if she had the musical resources to actually work a fugue on 'Love me or leave me?'   Not that I'm suggesting one would have improved this wonderful performance!